# Accessibility focus for view with touch delegate

Tags: android, touch, accessibility

I have the following code to expand touch delegate of a view

```
layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            view.getHitRect(rect);
            int extraPadding = 200;
            rect.top -= extraPadding;
            rect.left -= extraPadding;
            rect.right += extraPadding;
            rect.bottom += extraPadding;
            layout.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, view));
        }
    });
```

The touches in the extra touch area goes to the view(small view) correctly. My question is whether I can change bounding box of my view to be bigger to include the bigger area in talkback mode? (touch explore mode). Is there anything I can do to achieve that?